# gl_FragCoord equivalent in RenderScript ScriptC

Tags: android, glsl, shader, renderscript

I’m in the process to porting some GLSL shaders into Renderscript.

What would be the way to emulate the equivalence of **gl_FragCoord** in Renderscript ScriptC?

**GLSL Shader:**

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);

    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy) - vec2(0.5);
    float len = length(position);

    gl_FragColor = color * vec4(vec3(len), 1.0);
}
```

**Renderscript:**

```
rs_allocation texture;
rs_sampler sampler;
float2 resolution;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) root(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    float2 texcoord = (float2){(float)x, (float)y} * (float2){ 1.0f / resolution.x, 1.0f / resolution.y};
    float4 color = rsSample(texture, sampler, texcoord);

    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    float2 position = (***gl_FragCoord.xy*** / resolution.xy) - 0.5f;
    -----------------------------------------------------------------

    float len = length(position);
    color *= (float4){len, len, len, 1.0f}

    return rsPackColorTo8888(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have it in your code, the input `x` and `y` arguments are equivalent to `gl_FragCoord.xy`, also note that multiplying by the reciprocal of `resolution.xy` is the same as dividing by it in the first place:

```
float2 texcoord = (float2){(float)x, (float)y} / (float2){resolution.x, resolution.y};
```